# What do "ed:XXX" meaning in translated manga?

Tags: abbreviations

For example(8 page):
[http://mangahasu.se/onii-chan-wa-oshimai/vol-6-chapter-17-mahiro-and-the-onsen-
panic-first-part-c590411.html#8](http://mangahasu.se/onii-chan-wa-oshimai/vol-6-chapter-17-mahiro-and-the-onsen-%20panic-first-part-c590411.html#8)

I can't find a tool to query such abbreviations word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no frame of reference for Manga, but certainly in British humour comics there are often footnotes from the *Editor* which are abbreviated as "*Ed*".

These are usually for comic effect and are not actually from the editor of the publication; they are usually inserted intentionally by the writer / artist / letterer as a way of *breaking the fourth wall* (where characters in a work of fiction address the audience directly). It is similar to having a *narrator*, but deliberately breaks the illusion of reality by acknowledging that this is a comic.